# Problema al obtener id de un elemento al que se da click con jquery

Tags: jquery

Tengo este codigo jquery, lo que hace es que se ejecuta cuando se da click a un enlace:

```
<script>
 var num = 0;
 var texto;


$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').on('click', '#accordion a', function(){
      num = $(this).attr('id');
      temas(num);
  });
});

function temas(num)
{    
    $("#collapse" + num).on("hide.bs.collapse", function(){
     $(".enlace" + num).html("<span class='fa fa-toggle-down'></span> <a class='card-link' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#collapse" + num + "'  href='#collapse" + num + '"> " + texto + "</a>");
    });

    $("#collapse" + num).on("show.bs.collapse", function(){
     $(".enlace" + num).html("<span class='fa fa-toggle-up'></span> <a class='card-link' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#collapse" + num + "' href='#collapse" + num + "'"> " + texto + "</a>");
    });
}
</script>
```

Esos enlaces tienen un id y lo obtengo al dar click en alguno de ellos, cuando doy click aun enlace por primera vez si obtiene el id pero cuando a ese mismo enlace le doy click mas de una vez me marca id indefinido.

Por que esta pasando eso??

Comment: Sería mejor si generaras un [mcve] y que se pueda ejecutar en el snippet de SOes, lee [ask], saludos

Comment: en la primer funcion .html() te falta cerrar el span

Comment: la function temas te agrega un `html` con un elemento `a` dentro de el `span` que no le agregas id no se si a ese mismo a es al que le quieres dar `click` por segunda vez pero puede ser por eso que no te sale `undefined`

Comment: Sí, lo más probable es que al link que le da click no tenga el atributo id y por ello le retorna undefined

Comment: El error era que me faltaba agregarle el id al link y por ello es que me lo regresaba como indefinido

Answer (score 0):

intenta con este codigo :

```js
 $("#embedcode").html('<iframe src="embed.php?answerid=' + answerid + comments + '" width="550" height="' + $('#embed input[name="size"]').val() + '" frameborder="0"></iframe>');
```

como vez en el siguiente estamos usando Jquery y seleccionando el ID embedcode y con . html estamos agregando un frame al elemento que seleccionamos, este codigo lo puedes implementar en tu problema.

el codigo es de la siguiente pregunta : 
[stackoverflow english](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13809872/jquery-getting-id-of-clicked-link)

Comment: Agrega una explicación de qué hace este código